# what should be Ruby Safe navigator expression for account["details"]["name"]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

Trying to write with safe navigator :

```
account["details"]["name"]
```

below doesn't work with unknown method & error.

```
account&["details"]&["name"]
```

using jRuby9, rails-5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe navigator version would look like this:

```
account&.[]("details").&[]("name")
```

Or you might consider using [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
account.dig("details", "name")
```

Comment: `account&.[]("details").&[]("name")` works. thanks.